# How to only extract polygons cover by a set percentage of raster pixel?

Tags: r, vector, raster

I have look for help on this problem in many places and I can not seem to find the answer I am looking for. I want to create an R code to get a vector layer containing all the polygons respecting this rule: each polygons need that have 30% or more of its surface cover in pixel with the value 1. To give you a bit more context I have two layer (vector: [BDPPAD2014_crop](https://www.fadq.qc.ca/fileadmin/geo4tb/BDPPAD/BDPPAD_V03_2014.zip) =represent agricultural field in a region) (raster: degraded= represent a tif file containing pixel showing were these field are showing degradation). My goal is to be able to use R to extract all the field where 30% or more of the polygons area show degradation. I was able with the below code to get a vector layer, but when I look at it in QGIS ([image: see image]) I can clearly see that some of the polygons selected have no pixel on them which is not what I want since a pixel here mean degradation. Could someone help me understand where is the problem in my code? Thank you for your time and help with this :)

I try many different thing but here is what almost work:

### Loading the required layer

```
BDPPAD2014_crop<-st_read(dsn=paste0(path_name, "Data/Vector/BDPPAD2014_crop.shp"))
degraded <- raster(paste0(path_name, "Data/Raster/negativeSignificant_trend.tif"))
plot(degraded)
```

## Check the CRS compatibility

```
# Check the CRS compatibility
if (!identical(crs(BDPPAD2014_crop), crs(degraded))) {
  print("CRS mismatch. Reprojecting one of the layers to match the other's CRS.")
  # Reproject BDPPAD2014_crop to match degraded's CRS
  BDPPAD2014_crop <- st_transform(BDPPAD2014_crop, crs(degraded))
}
# Check spatial extent compatibility
extent_vector <- st_bbox(BDPPAD2014_crop)
extent_raster <- extent(degraded)

if (!identical(extent_vector, extent_raster)) {
  print("Spatial extent mismatch. Adjusting the extent of the raster to match the vector.")
  
  # Adjust the extent of the raster to match the vector
  extent_raster <- extent_vector
  extent(degraded) <- extent_raster
}
# Print the extents
cat("Extent of Vector Layer:\n", st_bbox(BDPPAD2014_crop), "\n")
# Extract the extent
raster_extent <- extent(degraded)

# Print the extent
print(raster_extent)
```

## Reclassify the raster

```
# All degraded pixels will have a value of 1
m = c(-Inf, 0, 1)
rcl = matrix(m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
degraded.rcl <- reclassify(degraded, rcl)
# Extract pixel values using exact_extract
pixel_values <- exact_extract(degraded.rcl, BDPPAD2014_crop)

# Calculate the percentage of 1s within each polygon
percentage_1s <- sapply(pixel_values, function(pixel_values) {
  if (length(pixel_values) == 0) return(NA)
  mean(pixel_values == 1, na.rm = TRUE) * 100
})

# Set the threshold percentage
threshold_percentage <- 30

# Filter polygons based on the threshold percentage using column "SUP" which contain the area of each polygons
selected_polygons <- BDPPAD2014_crop[percentage_1s >= threshold_percentage & BDPPAD2014_crop$SUP >= threshold_percentage, ]

# Check and print polygons that don't meet the threshold
non_compliant_polygons <- BDPPAD2014_crop[percentage_1s < threshold_percentage | BDPPAD2014_crop$SUP < threshold_percentage, ]
print(non_compliant_polygons)

# Plot the selected polygons vs the BDPPAD2014_crop 
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = BDPPAD2014_crop, fill = "lightgray") +
  geom_sf(data = selected_polygons, fill = "blue")

st_write(selected_polygons,dsn=paste0(path_name, "Data/Vector/20230919_selected_degradedfield.shp"))
```

Comment: What's your raster resolution?

Comment: My raster resolution is 30m

Comment: We arrive at degraded differently (as yours was based on data you had and mine was 'for example'), but does the approach below work for you?

Comment: Hi @Chris I try your code but still ran in some problem see below

Comment: Have you consider using [exactextract](https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/)? You can pass a function that uses the `coverage_fraction` and ignore values below that threshold. See more info in the docs, might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking down [crop data](https://www.fadq.qc.ca/documents/donnees/base-de-donnees-des-parcelles-et-productions-agricoles-declarees?chash=08233d5047ecfc9684bc34012ee1a1e7&l=1&cHash=7334cdf5236793034c792d96e9e2ccac), making up a degraded raster ((cell values set to 1 then reset by sampling), fiddling around getting `crs` and `extent` lined up as above, and taking a small cropped section from each, parcels and degraded, the following approach might work

```
library(terra)
# some objects

# smaller_agri = draw(x = 'extent') # get small num of parcels from all BD2014
# smaller_agri
#SpatExtent : -73.0458375577738, -72.9682494683782, 45.8925658029653, 45.9361554490149 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# smaller_agri2 = crop(agri_parcels, smaller_agri)
# small_agr2_rast = rast(smaller_agri2, extent = ext(smaller_agri2), nrows=1000, ncol=1000, crs = crs(smaller_agri2))
# degraded = rast(nrows = 1000, ncols = 1000, extent = ext(smaller_agri), crs = crs(smaller_agri))
# values(degraded) = 1
# degraded2 = crop(degraded, small_agri2, mask = TRUE) # also replaces your `classify`

# degraded2_1[not.na(degraded2_1)] = sample(c(0,1), length(which(values(degraded2_1) == 1)), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.71, 0.29))
# degraded2_1_crs = project(degraded2_1, small_agr2_rast) #set crs
# degrade_mean = terra::extract(degraded2_1_crs, smaller_agri2, FUN = mean)
dim(degrade_mean)
[1] 827209      2 # there are lots of layers...
names(degrade_mean)
[1] "ID"    "lyr.1" 

# this should get us there and can `<- crop(` of course
plot(crop(degraded2_1_crs, smaller_agri2[degrade_mean[,2] >= 0.29], mask = TRUE)) # which layers
plot(smaller_agri2[degrade_mean[, 2] >= 0.29], add = TRUE)
```

[image]

think this was what you were looking for.